# qemu props -where are they? what are they and where do I find them?

Tags: android-sdk

I want to disable task windows button so I used:

```
qemu.hw.mainkeys=1
```

And used Button Saviour.
However, I wonder whats more in qemu props, so I can tweak some more. In short:

Where are qemu props? what are they and where do I find them?

Comment: I've only ever seen qemu for the keys (as you have done) and for the emulator, not actually on device. The description on the emulator is `this program is used to read a set of system properties and their values from the emulator program and set them in the currently-running emulatedsystem. It does so by connecting to the 'boot-properties' qemud service.`  I'll have to get digging to see if there's more. http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page

Comment: OK thx. Still mystical...